looking for a good (free) beginner workout plan online
I have got myself into the habit now of working out 4-5 times a week at home, but I am looking for a bit more structure. I don't have the funds to pay for a personal trainer and looking online I have just got myself lost.
I am 45 years old, male, weigh 100KG (down from 140 when I started) consider myself a beginner in terms of setting up a programme, I enjoy doing supersets (feel like I get more work done in less time) and reading online it seems I am better off doing full body routines at my level of fitness, I am trying to just tone up a bit, lose some body fat and get healthier.
I have a bar, dumbells, kettle bells, a flat bench (doesn't incline or decline) and a rack so I can safely do chest press/sqaut etc.
Has anyone got any websites they could link me to with programmes detailed, or advice as to the best way to structure a routine across the week for myself.
I have been trying to do the below programme but I am struggling to get through all of the exercises every day through the week.
https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/dumbbell-barbell-mass-workout.html
Any advice greatly appreciated.
